# windows filtering platform event log for "Local Principals"

Tags: windows-firewall

I am able to get windows filtering platform (firewall) event log into Splunk. I have all the information such as destination, source, port, application, protocol.... however the only thing I am missing is Local Principals Users, I have googled and visited many sites and it seem like such valuable information is not being captured in the Event Log. Does anyone know how to get such information. I need to know which user is using the application, furthermore I want to use such information to tighten the firewall such as only allowing user1 to use application XYZ to visit 1.1.1.1

I know some of you might suggest AppLocker but, I run into a situation where I want to allow user2 to visit 1.1.1.2 but not 1.1.1.1, using AppLocker would block out user2.

[Scrennshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkLP8.png)

Here are some of event logs for windows filtering platform from Microsoft website. No indication that it logs "Local Principals Users". Is there verbosity that I can increased?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-5157

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wye2e.png)

Comment: maybe a commercial tool like ThreatLocker would be a fit?

Comment: Sorry. The reason why I am using WFP is because I need this to work in an air gapped environment. If you have another commercial tool that can work on-prem in an air gapped environment, please let me know.